# How to refactor when reflection is used to get methods by name?

Tags: c#, reflection, refactoring

Suppose I get a MethodInfo in the following way:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
Type type = assembly.GetType(nameSpaceName+"."+className);
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("myMethod", bf); // bf are the binding flags.
```

But later I decide to change the case/name of `myMethod`.

Is there a way to either:

1. Refactor so that it changes the name in the string.
2. Change the reflection call so it gets the method without using the method's name as a string?

The reason for this is so I can test my code which requires the use of reflection, but I'd rather not require that nobody ever change the name of the methods in the code.

Comment: In a word: carefully! It's really all going to depend on exactly how and why you're using reflection. What's special about the name `myMethod`? Does the class not implement an interface, or something like that?

Comment: Hm... I guess myMethod is special in that I know that another method calls it, myMethodCaller.  So when I test I expect to see the caller of myMethod as myMethodCaller.  I guess I can just expect not to change these two methods... but I don't like that.

Comment: Is it possible in your scenario to have the types in the dynamically loaded assemblies implement an interface?  That way you don't have to call methods via reflection at all (but can still have a plug in architecture).

Comment: @user420667: So how does your caller call the code? Directly? If so, why can't you do the same?

Comment: @JS:  B/c the point of the test is to show that some other method, say MethodInfo getCaller(MethodInfo mi), works.

Comment: @user420667: i was wondering what is your specific use-case.  I agree on the general -- you're sometimes forced to use strings to specify method names.  Have you looked at PostSharp for code weaving?

Comment: @GregC: my use-case is developing something that does what visual studio's find all references does.  I haven't looked into PostSharp yet but I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio to do the refactoring, there is an option to search literal strings and comments for the name and change those too. I highly recommend using the preview when using that option, though, to verify that you're only changing the parts you expect.

Of course, you could use a constant like `internal const string methodName = "methodName";` so that you only have the literal string once. You could manually change the one string literal when you refactor the method name. You'd also be able to rename the `methodName` more easily.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. never looked carefully at the refactor dialog.

Comment: This approach can get really ugly if the method name matches a string that is commonly used in comments.  There's got to be a better way.

Comment: @GregC: That's exactly why I told him to use the preview. Otherwise it can get pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom attribute, and decorate your methods with this attribute. Then instead of getting the method by its name, you could get it by the ID defined in the attribute. That way the method name could change as often as it needs to...just a thought.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CustomMethodAttribute(ID = "UniqueIDHere")]
public void Test()
{

}
```

Comment: Hm... interesting solution.  I guess you have to use this in combination with MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(CustomMethodAttribute, false/true).  Or is there another way?

Comment: Yep - just another option for you. Gives you more control over the naming convention, and you can customize GhostDoc to add the attribute in when you add your XML comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a concrete reference to the type in question?

Even if you don't have it explicitly, you can make the method generic.

```
public void TestMethod<TargetType>(object o)
{
    if (typeof(TargetType).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())) {
        TargetType strongType = o as TargetType;
        strongType.myMethod();
    }
}
```

In fact, you could do this without reflection at all:

```
public void TestMethod<TargetType>(object o)
{
    if (o is TargetType) {
        TargetType strongType = o as TargetType;
        strongType.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I am aware that I can call it directly, but it is not the point of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user420667, if you have to use dynamic invocation then obviously you can't bind to the method by name at compile time.  In that case, I would just use a `const string` for the method name and reference this const wherever you invoke dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

For methods and properties try using expression trees.
You can get reflection-related information from them, saving compile-time checking and enabling automatic refactoring.
I believe you can get assembly-related information and namespace names as well.
Just write several helper functions which can retrieve such information from expression trees.

You can find several helper functions [here](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ExtensionMethods/MvxNotifyPropertyExtensionMethods.cs)
They allow write such code:

```
FirePropertyChanged(() => PropertyName);
```

which is the same as

```
FirePropertyChanged("PropertyName");
```